# Twilio record completing "action:" with empty recording

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twilio, twilio-api, actionresult, twilio-programmable-voice

According to the Programmable Voice  documentation;  `if Twilio receives an empty recording, it will not make a request to the 'action' URL. The current call flow will continue with the next verb in the current TwiML document.`

I have (tried) writen my code such that the user is prompted to make a recording, and if no voice is detected during the recording duration, they receive another prompt, according to the following code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var response = new VoiceResponse();
                response.Say("hello, how can I help you today?");
                response.Record(action: Url.ActionUri("Show", "Voice"), playBeep: false, finishOnKey:"1");
                response.Say("please try again")
            return TwiML(response);
        }

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Show(string RecordingUrl)
        {
...
        }
```

However, even if the user does not speak while the call is recording, it POSTs to `ActionResult Show()` despite documentation stating it should do `response.Say("please try again")`. Am I interpreting the documentation incorrectly? How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check with support, accounts can have this feature turned on or off

Comment: Your answer is better suited as a comment.